# Let $G = S_n$, fix $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ and let $G_i = \{\sigma \in G ~|~ \sigma(i) = i\}$ .Then find $|G_i|?$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $G = S_n$, fix $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ and let $G_i = \{\sigma \in G ~|~ \sigma(i) = i\}$ .Then find $|G_i|?$.

**My attempt** :I think  $|G_i|= |S_n|$ because  $G_i$ permutes  all n elements of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

For example take  $S_3= G,$ $G_i = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ \sigma(i) = i\}$

Fix $i= \{1,2,3\}$.Element of $S_3$  are $\{1,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$

For $\sigma=(1)$

$G_1 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (1)(1) = 1\}$

$G_2 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (1)(2) = 2\}$

$G_3 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (1)(3) = 3\}$

For $\sigma=(12)$

$G_1 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (12)(1) = 1\}$

$G_2 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (12)(2) = 2\}$

$G_3 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (12)(3) = 3\}$

For $\sigma=(13)$

$G_1 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (13)(1) = 1\}$

$G_2 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (13)(2) = 2\}$

$G_3 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (13)(3) = 3\}$

For $\sigma=(23)$

$G_1 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (23)(1) = 1\}$

$G_2 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (23)(2) = 2\}$

$G_3 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (23)(3) = 3\}$

For $\sigma=(123)$

$G_1 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (123)(1) = 1\}$

$G_2 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (123)(2) = 2\}$

$G_3 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (123)(3) = 3\}$

For $\sigma=(132)$

$G_1 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (132)(1) = 1\}$

$G_2 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (132)(2) = 2\}$

$G_3 = \{\sigma \in S_3 ~|~ (132)(3) = 3\}$

For  fixed $i=1,2,3$  we have $|G_i|=3+3+3+3+3+3=18  $

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question.  It's asking how many permutation are there in $S_n$ that fix a given $i$.  It's not a hard question.  It's definitely not the case that $\vert S_n \vert = \vert G_1 \vert$ because the transposition $(i ~ i+1) \in S_n \setminus G_i$.

Comment: Isn't $G_i$ stabilizer of $i$? If you fix $i$, then $n-1$ symbols remain which can be arranged in $(n-1)!$ ways.

Comment: You are also misunderstanding the set notation. It is the set of all such sigma , you do not get to pick one

Comment: What the others said. I think that failing to understand set notation is holding you back when studying algebra. This is not uncommon! Shortcomings in elementary set theory is probably the most common reason why freshmen fail in my algebra classes! There are many reasons to this. My generation participated in an experiment where elementary set theory started in grade school. So as teachers we had to spend two decades learning that this is not clear to all and sundry. Secondly, the concepts and notation of sets is literally everywhere in math.

Comment: (cont'd) Meaning that all the teachers and textbook authors similarly assume that the students are 100% fluent with it. The misunderstandings are terrible to behold :-(

Comment: The sad part is that I cannot recommend a textbook that would explain this. Possibly one targeting (junior) high school. You need to ask local people for recommendations.

Comment: oks @Koro that means  for  fix $ i=\{12,3\} G_i$, we have two  different way  to fill in the blanks $\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2&3\\1&*&*\end{pmatrix}$.Am i right ?

Comment: Thank You for Your Suggestion  Sir @JyrkiLahtonen I've already told you   that  im a slow learner .Also, im not afraid to ask completely stupid question

Comment: @jasmine: yes, two different ways for that.